# MySQL Error 2049: Authentication protocol error

Tags: mysql

I'm having a problem while trying to remotely connect to my database server from my other server.
I receive the following error when i try to make a connection:

ERROR 2049 (HY000): Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol ref
used (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)

I've checked the **secure_auth** option on the database server, and it is **off**, and my client seems to have this option **activated** as the message says.
Is there any way to fix this by only modifying the settings on the database server?

Answer (score 1):

I was having this EXACT same problem, and this finally worked for me:

I uninstalled my local mysql client (I was running MySQL 5.6) and installed MySQL 5.5, and then restarted my computer.

I'm using Homebrew on my Mac, so I did this:

```
brew uninstall mysql
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install mysql55
brew link --force mysql55
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql55/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql55.plist
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql55.plist
```

Apparently my 5.6 client didn't want to use the less secure passwords that my company's servers were using, even though I had tried to turn off secure_auth locally. MySQL 5.5 doesn't complain about passwords being less secure, but 5.6 does.

Comment: This solved my problem.  MySQL 5.6 uses secure auth by default. No matter how hard I tried to turn off secure auth by having the string "skip-secure-auth" in the mysql group portion of my.cnf, and then loading my.cnf through php ($con=mysqli_init(); mysqli_options( $con, MYSQLI_READ_DEFAULT_FILE, "set skip-secure-auth=1;" (also tried using  set global secure_auth=1; or set global secure-auth=1 or set global secure-auth=true; or set global secure_auth=true using MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, however with the mysql CLI just having "skip-secure-auth in the mysql group worked show through mysqli --help).

Comment: Sorry in the above i meant set global secure_auth=false, secure_auth = 0, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have user accounts with passwords that used the ancient old hashing algorithm. Create a new user with new-style hash, and now use that new user with no trouble. Check [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69027) the related information

Comment: but with that error message, you could not even login. how do you create a new user?